# What view do I return for NSTextFinderClient's contentViewAtIndex:effectiveCharacterRange protocol method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiwebview, nsscrollview, objective-c-protocol

I've implemented an object that conforms to the `NSTextFinderClient` protocol.  The `textFinder`'s find bar container is a `WebView`'s `WebDynamicScrollBarsView`, which is an `NSScrollView`.  When I show the Find Bar in my `WebView` it calls the `NSTextFinderClient'`s implementation of string:, where I return the webView's document.body.innerText.  When I type into the Find Bar matches are found and appear to be enumerated while the `TextFinder` calls `scrollRangeToVisible` and `contentViewAtIndex:effectiveCharacterRange` on my `NSTextFinderClient` object, but nothing is highlighted.

Given this context, what should I return from my webview/scrollview for those two protocol methods in order for the `textFinder` to correctly highlight and scroll my webView?

Please note, this is a Mac application, I tagged `uiwebview` because there is no tag for the mac's WebView object and the webview tag is related to Android.